# How to describe the lower area of upper ray in a 'hockey stick'-shape angle?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, sports

I am trying to describe the area depicted below. It is the beginning of the upper ray coming from the vertex of the obtuse angle in a 'hockey stick'-shaped function. (In other words, it's an area past the vertex where the function begins to grow rapidly). Any suggestions? Keeping the reference to the hockey stick is a plus.

[image: Hockey Stick]

EDIT: Thanks to the suggestions below, I found this picture:

[image: Golf Club - annotated]

Does 'hosel' sound about right? Is this a word anyone would understand?

Comment: Heel?: http://howtohockey.com/hockey-stick-curve-guide/

Comment: The *bice*p (above the "elbow"), maybe? Or, following on Josh, the *ankle*? The *foot of the mountain*? I don't know enough about hockey to have any hockey-themed suggestions to offer.

Comment: That's a golf club, not hockey stick, so using *hosel*, you'd change the hockey metaphor to a golf one (which is fine if you're fine with it, of course!). That said, while personally I'm a big fan of using obscure jargon precisely, even better precisely *metaphorically*, the risk is no one's going to know what you're talking about. Not being a golfer or sports fan in general, I've never encountered the word "hosel" before, as an example.

Comment: Yeah - I fear that too, not knowing what I was trying to say. Thank you!

Comment: Well, that doesn't change the fact that I need to describe the function.

Comment: @Olga Sure, of course, but I'd be tempted to simply be descriptive and say something like  "at the beginning of the rise". Is there any particular factor which is requiring you to use a single word instead of being descriptive?

Comment: Beginning of the rise sounds good. It's just I am making a direct reference to a hockey stick :-) I have to because I am referring to a published article that uses the same jargon.

Comment: [This manufacturer's site](http://colthockey.com/blogs/colt-blog/19039351-30-hockey-stick-terms-you-should-know-when-buying-a-stick) confirms that *hosel* is used for "the section of the hockey stick where the blade and the shaft come together". The area of the blade immediately beyond it, where the slope changes direction, is the "heel".

Comment: In this context, *vertex* would be expected to be the same as apex. Vertex in the polygon sense is not used for smooth curves. And *hosel* doesn't refer to geometry, it refers to joinery.